# Is the locker room at the end of Men in Black 2 a pocket dimension/universe?

Tags: men-in-black-2

At the end of *Men in Black II* (2002), K and J walk to a door labeled "DANGER: EXIT! DO NOT OPEN". This is opened by K and the camera zooms out to show that it is a door to a locker in a row of seemingly infinite or at least very many other lockers. Huge monsters are walking around. Is this meant to say that the locker room is a pocket dimension within the MIB compound? Or that Earth and our universe is a pocket dimension inside the locker room?

Comment: Considering that they did the same thing in the 1st movie with the Galaxy marble, I'd say that's both to imply that Earth + our universe is a pocket dimension inside the locker room (and all of us are the equivalent to the locker civilization) and as nod to the previous movie

Comment: Let's just say, that final scene in MIB II did not make quite as much sense as the one in the original movie, especially when seen in conjunction with the latter, and overall lacks the connection to the movie's plot (the first movie had a miniature galaxy in a marble as a prize that several parties were after).